# Как получить текст из виджета Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я хотел бы получить весь текст, введенный пользователем, но не знаю, как это сделать:

```py
from tkinter import *

print("Hello, this is Python interpreter\nYou can enter your code in the window.")
# def interpreter(code):
#         pass

interpreter_window = Tk()
interpreter_window.title("Python")

coding = Text(interpreter_window, height=20, width=40)
coding.pack()
# s = coding.get(???)
# print(s)
#??????
interpreter_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ скопитырен [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-widget)

Вы можете получить текст следующим образом:

```
coding.get("1.0", END)
```

Здесь `"1.0"` означает первую строку и нулевой символ в строке, то есть с самого начала текста, `END` - до самого конца. В таком варианте в виджет добавится новая пустая строка. Чтобы этого избежать можно воспользоваться вот такой командой:

```
coding.get("1.0",'end-1c')
```

Здесь, `-1с` означает, что идем до самого конца и удаляем последний символ (который и будет символом новой строки). Для справки `-2с` удалит 2 символа и так далее