# Почему выводится .!текст2 , а не перевод?

Tags: python, tkinter, google-translate

```
import tkinter as tk
from googletrans import Translator


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.translator = Translator()
        self.title('Translate')
        self.geometry('600x400+400+150')

        self.text = tk.Text(self, width=15, height=3)
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.text_lan = tk.Text(self, width=15, height=3)
        self.text_lan.place(y=100, x=0)

        self.text_lan = str(self.text_lan)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Translate", command=self.translate)
        self.btn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e', padx=10)

    def translate(self):
        tr = self.translator.translate(self.text_lan, dest='ru').text
        print(tr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MainWindow()
    window.mainloop()
```

проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрите пример по ссылке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1122733/1365. Нужно делать именно как там показано, а не через  `str`

Comment: Все работает , спасибо большое